# How do i expand my custom dict subclass into function arguments in python

Tags: python, function, dictionary, subclass

so i'm subclassing python dict to only allow certain fields in order to use it as an options map. When i unpack it in my function call i want that the type of the custom dict inside the function is still my subclass.

e.g.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

class Options(dict):

    _keys = ['a', 'b', 'c']

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):

        for key, val in kwargs.items():
            if key not in self._keys:
                raise KeyError

        super().__init__(self, **kwargs)

    def __setitem__(self, key, val):
        if key not in self._keys:
            raise KeyError
        else:
            super().__setitem__(self, key, val)


def foo(**kwargs):
    print(type(kwargs))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    options = Options(a=1, b=2, c=3)
    print(type(options))
    foo(**options)
```

output:

```
<class '__main__.Options'>
<class 'dict'>
```

What i want is that kwargs inside foo is of type Options.
Is this possible without messing with python internals?
I guess i could just do without the unpacking but i like to have consistent IO syntax.

Thanks

edit:

i worked around this by doing:

```
def foo(**kwargs):
    kwargs = Options(**kwargs)
    print(type(kwargs))
```

Comment: ** is `keyword argument dictionary` and thats why you will always get `dict` for `kwargs`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please correct me if I am wrong, but I believe the optional function arguments `*args` and `**kwargs` are by definition of type `tuple` and `dict` respectively.

The reason for my assumption is that these optional arguments are *passed by value*, i.e. Python makes a local copy to be used in the function. See the example:

```
class MyDict(dict):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(self, **kwargs)


def test(**kwargs) -> None:
    kwargs['a'] = 'b'
    print(kwargs)


d = MyDict(a='a')
print(d)
test(**d)
print(d)
```

Resulting in:

```
{'a': 'a'}
{'a': 'b'}
{'a': 'a'}
```

Consequently, in order to retain well-defined behaviour it makes perfect sense that you are not allowed to set the `type` of `kwargs`.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, i expected something like that. The point about passing by value is interesting though and i didnt think of that.